# HTML fullscreen API on DIV

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, fullscreen

Is HTML fullscreen working on DIVs?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
</head><body>
<div id="e">fullscreen</div>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("e");
        if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen)
        {
            elem.innerHTML += " has function";
            elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }
    }
</script>
</body></html>
```

It outputs `fullscreen has function` on Chrome. However no fullscreen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to be triggered by a user action: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/cHuNr/show/

```
var div = document.querySelector("div"),
    btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (div.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        div.innerHTML += " has function";
        div.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
});
```